# Python replacing values using index and/or values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

consider:

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

I have to make take all items in list b that correspond to the value of 1 in the list a. Then change all occurrences to those items in **both** lists to 0.

Important Edit: I also have to take these items as input.

I have to also do this simultaneously for all items.

I have tried using a for loop to do this but for loop goes through the list one by one instead of all together.

I am honestly confused on how to approach this. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
NOTE: Has to be python 3.X

**Super Edit:** (Sorry I didn't do this earlier)

I want the code to go something like this:

input:

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 2, 2, 0, 0]
count = 0
```

output:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
count = 1
```

where count is supposed to increment as the numbers are changed.
Thus I have to go through the lists and do the steps described above simultaneously for all items and lists.
Sorry I didn't put this up earlier.

Comment: Can you please write the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should read `a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]` and `b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` if I am not mistaken

Comment: @Grimlock How do you imagine the procedure to achieve your goal should lookalike?

Comment: @Thomas I have updated the explanation

Comment: @hygull I have written out the output now

Comment: Still unclear to me what do you mean by "simultaneously", do you want to end up with a multithreading or asyncio solution? Please be more specific than repetitive...

Comment: ignore my previous comment I still havent found an answer. Also @Thomas something like that would be great

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do what you are asking and are looking for speed this will work:

```
[0 if x in b else x for x in a]
```

This will work, I am sure but slower than the above approach. But this will help in better understanding.

```
newa=[]
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        newa.append(0)
    else:
        newa.append(i)
```

the newa will be :

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that the for loop goes through the items one by one. I need a way to go through them all simultaneously

Comment: @Grimlock Why has it to happen simultaneous?

Comment: @inder can you write that without list comprehension

Comment: @Grimlock I am sorry I don't think I follow, without list comprehension meaning ???

Comment: @Grimlock I don't think that what you request for is actually feasible… like list-comprehensions in python is "the thing" to do… somehow you need to traverse the list as there is no such thing as a "one-shot-solution" to this.

Answer (score 1):

A first solution, using a loop:

```
def with_loop(a, b):
    out = []
    for index, val in enumerate(a):
        if val == 1:
            out.append(b[index])
            a[index] = 0
            b[index] = 0
    return out


a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 2, 2, 0, 0]

print(with_loop(a, b))
# [3 2 0]
print(a)
# [0 0 0 0 2]
print(b)
# [0 0 2 0 0]
```

Some timings:

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 2, 2, 0, 0]
%timeit with_loop(a, b)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 806 ns per loop

a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2]*20
b = [3, 2, 2, 0, 0]*20
%timeit with_loop(a, b)
#100000 loops, best of 3: 7.3 µs per loop

a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2]*400
b = [3, 2, 2, 0, 0]*400
%timeit with_loop(a, b)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 165 µs per loop
```

If your lists are large, it could be good to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 2, 2, 0, 0])


def with_numpy(a, b):
    out = b[a == 1]
    b[a == 1] = 0
    a[a == 1] = 0
    return out

print(with_numpy(a, b))
# [3 2 0]
print(a)
# [0 0 0 0 2]
print(b)
# [0 0 2 0 0]
```

Again, some timings:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 2, 2, 0, 0])
%timeit with_numpy(a, b)
#100000 loops, best of 3: 5.02 µs per loop

a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2]*20)
b = np.array([3, 2, 2, 0, 0]*20)
%timeit with_numpy(a, b)
#100000 loops, best of 3: 5.34 µs per loop

a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2]*400)
b = np.array([3, 2, 2, 0, 0]*400)
%timeit with_numpy(a, b)
#100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop
```

For small lists, using `numpy` has a big overhead, but it gets faster than the pure Python loops solution with lists less than 100 items long, and is more than 10 times faster for 2000 items.

Comment: This is pretty comprehensive but you might've just succeeded in overwhelming some kid trying to get his homework done. Not that there's a problem with that, but eh...

Comment: alright so my lists are never going to be too long so I'll go with the first solution. However, if there is a 1 in list a and 0 in list b I have to go back and turn the item in list b that corresponds to 0 in list a.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator which inspects both sequences and yields their current and future values:

```
def gen(a,b):
    for i in len(a):
        if a[i]==1:
            yield b[i] # need some cleverness about how we unpack this
            yield (0,0)
        else:
            yield None
            yield (a[i],b[i])
```

Then something like assign `a,b = list(gen(a,b))`. We'll need extra code to unpack the current nonzero elements of b

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to remove the `1`s from `list` a too, please have a look at this solution proposal:

```
>>> x, y = map(list, zip(*[(0 if i==1 else i, 0 if i==1 else j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]))
>>> print('x: {}, y: {}'.format(x, y))
x: [0, 0, 0, 0, 2], y: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

Please keep in mind that there actually is a need to traverse the list and that there is no other way to do this except going through the list one by one.